# Ubuntu 18.04 with nvidia-390 - user sessions not starting

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, 18.04

After upgrading to ubuntu 18.04, my nvidia driver was updated to version nvidia-390 and now I'm unable to login from lightdm with regular users. I tried other display managers, but I have the same issue.

What is really odd, is that I'm actually able to login with root and nvidia driver enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1773113

Currently there is no solution but I've just posted a suggestion that needs verifying, try creating a file with these lines:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia.conf
options nvidia_390_drm modeset=1
options nvidia_drm modeset=1
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an Intel GPU and am experiencing the same issues.

lightdm and gdm3 do not work

Though lxdm does work with LXDE. And even that eventually dies.

I haven't tried logging in as root yet.

Comment: How come this is an answer?

Comment: Not an answer, unfortunately, but a suggestion that nvidia is not the problem